# How to plot a graph with data gaps in Zeppelin?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

Dataframe was extracted to a temp table to plot the data density per time unit (1 day):

```
val dailySummariesDf =
      getDFFromJdbcSource(SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate(), s"SELECT *  FROM values WHERE time > '2020-06-06' and devicename='Voltage' limit 100000000")
        .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
    .groupBy($"digital_twin_id", window($"time", "1 day")).count().as("count")    
    .withColumn("windowstart", col("window.start"))
    .withColumn("windowstartlong", unix_timestamp(col("window.start")))
    .orderBy("windowstart")    


 dailySummariesDf. 
 registerTempTable("bank")
```

Then I plot it with `%sql` processor

```
%sql
select   windowstart, count
from bank
```

and

```
%sql
select   windowstartlong, count
from bank
```

What I get is shown below:

[image]

So, my expectation is to have gaps in this graph, as there were days with no data at all. But instead I see it being plotted densely, with October days plotted right after August, not showing a gap for September.

How can I force those graphs to display gaps and regard the real X axis values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, grouping a dataset by `window` column won't produce any rows for the intervals that did not contain any original rows within those intervals.

One way to deal with that I can think of, is to add a bunch of fake rows ("manually fill in the gaps" in raw dataset), and only then apply a `groupBy/window`. For your case, that can be done by creating a trivial one-column dataset containing all the dates within a range you're interested in, and then joining it to your original dataset.

Here is my quick attempt:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// Define sample data
val df = Seq(("a","2021-12-01"),
  ("b","2021-12-01"),
  ("c","2021-12-01"),
  ("a","2021-12-02"),
  ("b","2021-12-17")
).toDF("c","d").withColumn("d",to_timestamp($"d"))

// Define a dummy dataframe for the range 12/01/2021 - 12/30/2021
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
val start = DateTime.parse("2021-12-01",DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")).getMillis/1000
val end = start + 30*24*60*60
val temp = spark.range(start,end,24*60*60).toDF().withColumn("tc",to_timestamp($"id".cast(TimestampType))).drop($"id")

// Fill the gaps in original dataframe
val nogaps = temp.join(df, temp.col("tc") === df.col("d"), "left")

// Aggregate counts by a tumbling 1-day window
val result = nogaps.groupBy(window($"tc","1 day","1 day","5 hours")).agg(sum(when($"c".isNotNull,1).otherwise(0)).as("count"))
result.withColumn("windowstart",to_date(col("window.start"))).select("windowstart","count").orderBy("windowstart").show(false)
+-----------+-----+                                                             
|windowstart|count|
+-----------+-----+
|2021-12-01 |3    |
|2021-12-02 |1    |
|2021-12-03 |0    |
|2021-12-04 |0    |
|2021-12-05 |0    |
|2021-12-06 |0    |
|2021-12-07 |0    |
|2021-12-08 |0    |
|2021-12-09 |0    |
|2021-12-10 |0    |
|2021-12-11 |0    |
|2021-12-12 |0    |
|2021-12-13 |0    |
|2021-12-14 |0    |
|2021-12-15 |0    |
|2021-12-16 |0    |
|2021-12-17 |1    |
|2021-12-18 |0    |
|2021-12-19 |0    |
|2021-12-20 |0    |
+-----------+-----+
```

For illustration purposes only :)

Comment: This approach works, but.. It fails on 1) exiting limits of the output, by default 1000 per item. 2) overall memor limitation per output. So currently there is no option of the standard plot just to regard the timestamps on the timespam-type  axis? And te only way here to find the external plotters?

Comment: Yeah, I dont know if you can make graph processor interpolate missing points, sorry.