# Visibility of temproray tables and database tables in Spark SQL, is it possible to make a nested query to temprorary table from usual jdbc query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have a `DataFrame` put as temprorary table

```
val dailySummariesDfVisualize =
      dailySummariesDf
    .orderBy("event_time").registerTempTable("raw")
```

I can do some extraction from it with Spark SQL:

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM raw")
df.show()
```

And the output works. Then I'd like to do a nested query to the temprorary table inside the JDBC database query like that:

```
val dailySensorData =
getDFFromJdbcSource(SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate(), 
          s"SELECT *  FROM values WHERE time in (SELECT event_time FROM raw) limit 1000000")
           .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
dailySensorData.show(400, false)
```

And here I get the exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "raw" does not exist
```

If I try to execute in inside the `sqlContext.sql()` like that

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM values WHERE time in (SELECT event_time FROM raw)")
df.show()
```

i get:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: values; line 1 pos 14;
'Project [*]
+- 'Filter 'time IN (list#4967 [])
   :  +- 'Project ['event_time]
   :     +- 'UnresolvedRelation [raw]
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation [values]

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:106)
```

like both values (real jdbc table) and raw (temprorary table) are not visible form it. How can I use temp table in the nested queries?

UPD

According to mazaneicha I have tried (retrieve all values here, since not able to restrics them with nested query):

```
val dailySummariesDfVisualize =
      dailySummariesDf
    .orderBy("event_time").createOrReplaceTempView("raw") 

val dailySensorData =
      getDFFromJdbcSource(SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate(), 
      s"SELECT *  FROM values").createOrReplaceTempView("values")     

val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM values WHERE time in (SELECT event_time FROM raw)")
df.explain(true)
```

and here is the logical plan:

```
= Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [*]
+- 'Filter 'time IN (list#5475 [])
   :  +- 'Project ['event_time]
   :     +- 'UnresolvedRelation [raw]
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation [values]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
devicename: string, value: double, time: timestamp, coffee_machine_id: string, digital_twin_id: string, write_time: timestamp
Project [devicename#5457, value#5458, time#5459, coffee_machine_id#5460, digital_twin_id#5461, write_time#5462]
+- Filter time#5459 IN (list#5475 [])
   :  +- Project [event_time#4836]
   :     +- SubqueryAlias raw
   :        +- Sort [event_time#4836 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
   :           +- Relation[event_type#4835,event_time#4836,event_payload#4837,coffee_machine_id#4838,digital_twin_id#4839] JDBCRelation((SELECT *  FROM events WHERE (event_time > '2021-03-31'  or event_time < '2021-03-30') and event_type != 'Coffee_Capsule_RFID_Event' and event_type!='Coffee_Cup_RFID_Event' limit 2000000) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_48) [numPartitions=1]
   +- SubqueryAlias values
      +- Relation[devicename#5457,value#5458,time#5459,coffee_machine_id#5460,digital_twin_id#5461,write_time#5462] JDBCRelation((SELECT *  FROM values) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_65) [numPartitions=1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Join LeftSemi, (time#5459 = event_time#4836)
:- Relation[devicename#5457,value#5458,time#5459,coffee_machine_id#5460,digital_twin_id#5461,write_time#5462] JDBCRelation((SELECT *  FROM values) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_65) [numPartitions=1]
+- Project [event_time#4836]
   +- Relation[event_type#4835,event_time#4836,event_payload#4837,coffee_machine_id#4838,digital_twin_id#4839] JDBCRelation((SELECT *  FROM events WHERE (event_time > '2021-03-31'  or event_time < '2021-03-30') and event_type != 'Coffee_Capsule_RFID_Event' and event_type!='Coffee_Cup_RFID_Event' limit 2000000) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_48) [numPartitions=1]

== Physical Plan ==
SortMergeJoin [time#5459], [event_time#4836], LeftSemi
:- *(2) Sort [time#5459 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(time#5459, 200), true, [id=#1219]
:     +- *(1) Scan JDBCRelation((SELECT *  FROM values) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_65) [numPartitions=1] [devicename#5457,value#5458,time#5459,coffee_machine_id#5460,digital_twin_id#5461,write_time#5462] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<devicename:string,value:double,time:timestamp,coffee_machine_id:string,digital_twin_id:str...
+- *(4) Sort [event_time#4836 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(event_time#4836, 200), true, [id=#1224]
      +- *(3) Scan JDBCRelation((SELECT *  FROM events WHERE (event_time > '2021-03-31'  or event_time < '2021-03-30') and event_type != 'Coffee_Capsule_RFID_Event' and event_type!='Coffee_Cup_RFID_Event' limit 2000000) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_48) [numPartitions=1] [event_time#4836] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<event_time:timestamp>
```

Comment: You should be able to use JDBC to create `values` dataframe without `WHERE` clause, register temp view `"values"`, and then run a SQL against both temp views. Please also note that `registerTempTable` is deprecated since long time ago, try using `createTempView` instead.

Comment: @mazaneicha that would be problematic because of performance, as values are really huge, so I hoped that using results of nested query to the temp table/view will reduce the jdbc interaction with db

Comment: Can you share the `.explain()` from that?

Comment: @mazaneicha just added the physical plan to the post

Comment: I see what you mean, that ends up reading the whole `values` :( 
The only other option I can think of is to `.collectAsList()` keys from `raw`, and use this list to create the `IN` clause.

Comment: @mazaneicha I have succeed with making the complicated where clause with string formatting in Scala, thank you!

Comment: @mazaneicha sorry for asking that, but may be you have some relevant experience in that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70363651/how-to-plot-data-graph-in-zeppelin-not-ommiting-empty-x-axis-values-i-e-showing ? If yes could you please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mazaneicha's advice, I was able to resolve that with producing the where clause in scala from the DataFramw Rows, which are not so numerous compared to the data from whom I do the extraction query:

```
var collectedString = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()

for (row <- dailySummariesDfVisualize.collectAsList())
  {
      println(row(1))
      val start = row(1)
      val end = row(5)
      val timeSelection = s" time > ' ${start}' and  time < '${end}'"
      collectedString+=timeSelection    
  }

val whereClause = collectedString.mkString(" or ")
println(whereClause)

val dailySensorData =
      getDFFromJdbcSource(SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local").getOrCreate(), 
      s"SELECT *  FROM values WHERE "+whereClause+" limit 1000000")
       .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)    

dailySensorData.show(400, false)
```

It does the output what I was actually needed with acceptable performance.

The formatted whereClause output is something like:

```
time > ' 2021-03-24 07:06:34.0' and  time < '2021-03-24 07:08:34.0' or  time > ' 2021-03-24 07:07:41.0' and  time < '2021-03-24 07:09:41.0' or  time > ' 2021-03-24 07:07:43.0' and  time < '2021-03-24 07:09:43.0'
```

and so on